# how to show progress loading while Image not downloaded

Tags: android, android-glide, progress

i'm trying to set `progressdialog` or `progressbar` while images not downloaded , i already use image located in **drawable** folder , i set this image as **default image** while pictures not downloaded . how i can repace **default image** by `progress`  like this :

[image]

JAVA :

```
public class Art extends Fragment {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
GridView myGrid;
CategoryAdapter adapter;

public Art() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup  container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final ArrayList<String> movieList =  new ArrayList<>();
    movieList.add("https://myimage.com");
    movieList.add("https://myimage.com");
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_art, container, false);
    myGrid= (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridViewCategory);
    adapter =new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(),movieList);
    myGrid.setAdapter(adapter);
    myGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new   android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent popup = new Intent(getActivity(), Pop.class);
                    popup.putExtra("WallpaperURL", movieList.get(position));
                    startActivity(popup);
        }
    });
    return v;
   }
}
class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private Context context;
   private ArrayList<String> imageId=new ArrayList<String>();
    CategoryAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> imageId){
    this.context=context;
    this.imageId=imageId;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageId.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return imageId.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
class ViewHolder{
    ImageView CategoryImage;
    ViewHolder(View view){
        CategoryImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cat_imageView);
    }
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder=null;
    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)    context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.picture_item,parent,false);
        holder=new ViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder=(ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
      Glide.with(context).load(imageId.get(position)).placeholder(R.drawable.arrw).into(holder.CategoryImage);
      return row;
      }
   }
```

Comment: As far as I understand you want to show progress while your image is being downloaded ?

Comment: @Umair that's what I need!

Comment: @AliILa
Please see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want like this

```
view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//enable loading

Glide.with(context)
     .load(IMAGES.get(position))
     .error(R.drawable.matrade_logo2)
     .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
     .listener(new RequestListener < String, GlideDrawable > () {
         @Override
         public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target < GlideDrawable > target, boolean isFirstResource) {
             //
             return false;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target < GlideDrawable > target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
             // hide loading if image finished downloading
             return false;
         }
     })
     .into(imageView);
```

Comment: what about picture_item.xml ? 

<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for inflaters or overriding `getView()`, you're just unnecessarily slowing and complicating your app. It is simpler using views visiblity.

- Create both progress view and `ImageView` in your layout and make the `ImageView` gone.
- Make an `AsyncTask` that downloads the image and sets it to the `ImageView` and execute it.
- On `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute`, make the progress view gone and the `ImageView` visible.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing it right. If you want to download an image best way is to do it using asyncTask class. Try something like this it will help you for sure. or use some library like Glide, Picasso etc. Here is how you can do without using some library.

```
  private class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, File> 
  {
    String downloadedFilePath = "";
    String fileName = "";

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     */

    DownloadFileFromURL(String fName) {
        fileName = fName;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        onCreateDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("ResultOfMethodCallIgnored")
    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count = 0;
        File convertedFile = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);

            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();
            // getting file length
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
            String contentType = connection.getContentType();


            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream to write file
            downloadedFilePath = getActivity().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(downloadedFilePath);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        progressDialogForDownload.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     **/

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(File file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        if (progressDialogForDownload != null && progressDialogForDownload.isShowing()) {
            progressDialogForDownload.dismiss();
            progressDialogForDownload = null;
        }

        openFileWithIntent(this.downloadedFilePath);
    }

}
```

and in this method `openFileWithIntent(this.downloadedFilePath);`you can pass the downloaded path of image where ever you want to show it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
showLoader(); //show loader or progress here
Glide
    .with( context ) // could be an issue!
    .load(url)
    .asBitmap()
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {  
           @Override
           public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation glideAnimation){
              //hide loader or progress here
              imageView1.setImageBitmap( bitmap );
          }
      });
 }
```